# Create a New Form Based on Selected Checklist from Previous Form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Basically I want to create a form that on submit would create a new form based on the checklist selection.

For instance, when looking at my code, if I checked Section 1, Test Item 2 and submitted it. On submit it would pull up a new page (or load onto the current page) the more in depth steps. I'm trying to make a template to use on multiple documents, so just adding it in right there won't do it for me.

(1) How do I make Section 1, 2, and 3 to have nothing until checked? Instead of having to click the checkbox twice to make it go away, I'd rather have it not be there and appear when checked.

(2) I want the All checklist to check all the boxes but not show or hide them (I know this isn't coded right for this but I don't know how)

Here's my code: http://jsfiddle.net/kNsW9/2/

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#all').click(function(){
        if ($('#all').is(':checked'))
            $(this).nextAll('li').show();
        else
            $(this).nextAll('li').hide();
    });

    $('#1').click(function(){
        if ($('#1').is(':checked'))
            $(this).nextUntil('ol').show();
        else
            $(this).nextUntil('ol').hide();
    });

    $('#2').click(function(){
        if ($('#2').is(':checked'))
            $(this).nextUntil('ol').show();
        else
            $(this).nextUntil('ol').hide();
    });

    $('#3').click(function(){
        if ($('#3').is(':checked'))
            $(this).nextUntil('ol').show();
        else
            $(this).nextUntil('ol').hide();
    });
});
</script>
<form>
Table of Contents<br />
Please Select What to Test:<br />
<input type="checkbox" id="all" onclick="check(this.id)"></input>All
<ol><input type="checkbox" id="1"></input>Section 1
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 1</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 2</li>
</ol>
<ol><input type="checkbox" id="2"></input>Section 2
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 1</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 2</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 3</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 4</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 5</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 6</li>
</ol>
<ol><input type="checkbox" id="3"></input>Section 3
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 1</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 2</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 3</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 4</li>
<li><input type="checkbox"></input>Test Item 5</li>
</ol>
<!--<input type="submit" value="Submit">-->
</form>
```

Comment: Do you want the all (once unchecked) to uncheck all the boxes as well?

Comment: I've updated my code, not sure but it may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know how this works for you...

http://jsfiddle.net/kNsW9/9/

*I updated with css controlling the LI's visibilty instead of jquery
Checking all will check all sub items, unchecking all will uncheck all sub items

*I'm assuming that if you check all, then uncheck a subitem that all should be unchecked as well, right?

```
$('#all').click(function(){
    var checked = $(this).prop('checked');
    $('#section1,#section2,#section3').each(function() {
        $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
    });
});
```

Comment: There is one thing, currently if someone checks all, then unchecks a section, it unchecks the all checkbox, appropriately, however, if you recheck all sections (independently) it doesn't check the all checkbox... if this makes sense... lol, so not sure if you want it to act that way or not...

Answer (score 1):

I Made some changes in your jsfiddle, not sure if this is what your looking for. let me know if this is it or if I misunderstood the question:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/kNsW9/4/

you are in the right direction just had to make small changes

```
$('#1').nextUntil('ol').hide()
$('#2').nextUntil('ol').hide();
$('#3').nextUntil('ol').hide();

$('#all').click(function(){
    $('#1').click();
    $('#2').click();
    $('#3').click();
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  After thinking of it though, I'm going to change it up on you.  What if I want all check boxes to be checked / not based on the all check.

Comment: Can you elaborate, what do you mean all checkboxes to be checked, so when user clicks all "everything should be checked in all sections"?

Comment: When the "All" checkbox is checked it would essentially be a select all.  So all "Sections" and "Test Items" would be checked.